# How to get only latest record on filter of foreign key

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I have a table like this

Event table

| id | status | date | order(FK) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Planned | 05-02-2015 | 1 |
| 2 | Delivered | 04-02-2015 | 2 |
| 3 | Packed | 03-02-2015 | 3 |
| 4 | Return | 06-02-2015 | 1 |

I want output like this

| id | status | date | order(FK) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Delivered | 04-02-2015 | 2 |
| 3 | Packed | 03-02-2015 | 3 |
| 4 | Return | 06-02-2015 | 1 |

I tried with

```
query = Event.objects.annotate(order_num=Max('date'))
```

but didn't get the expected result.
How can I achieve this output?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using the following:

```
from django.db.models import Max

Event.objects.annotate(max_date=Max('order__event__date')) \
             .filter(date=F('max_date'))
```