# Get id of object with maximum field in Django

Tags: django

Let's say that in Django I have a Publisher model and a Book model connected to it in a one-to-many relationship.  And let's further say that the book has a `times_checked_out` field.  How do I get back a queryset of the ids of the most checked out book for each publisher?

What I cannot do is something like

```
Publisher.objects.annotate(max_book = Max('books__times_checked_out'))
```

because that returns the maximum check-outs, not the book with the maximum check-outs.  I also cannot think how to add in a `Case(When())` in a helpful way.  What is the way to do this in Django?

Comment: Do you want, 1) ids of max checked out book of every publisher (a list), 2) id of max checked out book in overall?

Comment: I want the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this in reverse, and get a queryset of Books that represent the highest `times_checked_out` per Publisher:

```
books = Book.objects\
  .order_by('publisher', '-times_checked_out')\
  .distinct('publisher')
```

An alternative (but more complicated approach) is this:

```
from django.db.models import Max, F

books = Book.objects\
  .annotate(max_checkout=Max('publisher__books__times_checked_out'))\
  .filter(times_checked_out=F('max_checkout'))
```

Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46353781/393652)

More about using [F expressions in filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#using-f-expressions-in-filters).